# Good UI builder for android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, user-interface

I'm developing an android application for my University Project. I have developed the UI with the built in XML editor in eclipse, but it doesn't give a good look. I've seen plenty of applications with good and easy UI integration but I've no idea on how they did it. I did an internet search and found out HTML is used to develop the UI but haven't found any good tutorial. if you can tell me a good UI generator with tutorials to learn that would be great. I'm a learner in android so I would appreciate your kind help.

Thank you.

Comment: eclipse + android plugin is the way to go

Comment: If you are a beginner,I would suggest not to use any builder or generator...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dimal, there is no royal short-cut to designing good user interfaces. It is why some call programming an 'art'. The Eclipse plugin isn't that bad. A stand-alone tool is DroidDraw but I doubt if you'll like it. My advise is to go through all the apps in the samples directory, and in the APIDemos. Pick the parts you'll like and use the code. You can also make your own custom views by extending the View class and overriding the Draw method. Basically there are no limits to making GUIs on Android.

Comment: thanks for the support! I actually built my UI, but I wanted to make is more interesting.. :)

Comment: And you, for the accept Dimal.

Answer (score 0):

The best native android user interfaces are rarely built with the UI builder tool. In order to have good control of everything, you'll want to edit the XML by yourself.

It's really not all that scary, and the eclipse tools do a good job with autocomplete, and pointing you towards problems.